# Images appear in different order each time I enter in the scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a scene where I show multiple images downloaded from a server. It works fine but the images are shown in a different order each time I enter in the scene and I want to appear always in the same order. Can anybody help me?

This is the code:

```
public GameObject contentRef;
public RawImage imgPrefab;

void Start()
{
DownloadtheFiles();
}

public void DownloadtheFiles()
{

List<string> photolist = ES2.LoadList<string>("myPhotos.txt");

for (int i = 0; i < photolist.Count; i++)
{
    //Don't capture i variable
    int index = i;

    new GetUploadedRequest()

        .SetUploadId(photolist[index])
        .Send((response) =>
        {
            StartCoroutine(DownloadImages(response.Url, index));
        });
}
}


public IEnumerator DownloadImages(string downloadUrl, int index)
{
var www = new WWW(downloadUrl);
yield return www;

//Instantiate the image prefab GameObject and make it a child of the contentRef
RawImage newImg = Instantiate(imgPrefab, contentRef.transform);
//Change the name
newImg.name = "Image-" + index;

//Get the downloaded image
Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(4, 4);
www.LoadImageIntoTexture(tex);

//Apply the downloaded image
newImg.texture = tex;
}
```

And these are a screenshots of the different images places when I enter in the scene twice:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Coroutines are a Unity specific way to do Multitasking. Once you start multiple tasks, the order in wich they finish is no longer deterministic. You could maybe make a single CoRoutine that does all the downloading and dispalying in a given order. But doing so might be bad for Network performance (many small files can benefit from downloading a lot of files in paralell).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WWW` API is threaded to so that it doesn't block your Unity game when you use it. This Thread is managed with the coroutine by using `yield return www;` to wait for the request when until it has finished. You are using the for loop to call the `DownloadImages` function which downloads the images. The problem is that the `WWW` call does not block the request and will finish depending on the size of the data/image and how long it took the server to respond.

If you want the images to download in order, you have to make the `DownloadtheFiles` function to be a coroutine function instead of a `void` function. After this, when you call `StartCoroutine(DownloadImages(response.Url, index));`, wait for it to return or finish before continuing with the for loop. Usually, a simple `yield return` is used for this but since you are calling `StartCoroutine` from a lambda, a callback with `Action` is more appropriate here. You can use `boolean` variable with an `Action` to tell the for loop that the current DownloadImages is done so that the it can continue.

```
public GameObject contentRef;
public RawImage imgPrefab;

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(DownloadtheFiles());
}

public IEnumerator DownloadtheFiles()
{
    yield return null;

    List<string> photolist = ES2.LoadList<string>("myPhotos.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < photolist.Count; i++)
    {
        //Don't capture i variable
        int index = i;

        bool reqDone = false;

        new GetUploadedRequest()

            .SetUploadId(photolist[index])
            .Send((response) =>
            {
                StartCoroutine(DownloadImages(response.Url, index,
                    (status) => { reqDone = status; }));


                //return null;
            });

        //Wait in the for loop until the current request is done
        while (!reqDone)
            yield return null;
    }
}

public IEnumerator DownloadImages(string downloadUrl, int index, Action<bool> done)
{
    var www = new WWW(downloadUrl);
    yield return www;

    //Instantiate the image prefab GameObject and make it a child of the contentRef
    RawImage newImg = Instantiate(imgPrefab, contentRef.transform);
    //Change the name
    newImg.name = "Image-" + index;

    //Get the downloaded image
    Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(4, 4);
    www.LoadImageIntoTexture(tex);

    //Apply the downloaded image
    newImg.texture = tex;

    //Done
    if (done != null)
        done(true);
}
```

---

Another solution is to download the Textures and store them in a List *but don't instantiate* them. When the for loop finish running, sort the `List` by name then instantiate the RawImage from the List.

Comment: Fantastic!!! It works fine now. The images appear in the right order but a little slow. Is it possible the images appear faster?

Comment: You can make it appear faster by implementing the second method I mentioned after the code. Don't forget to accept answer if I fixed your "appear order issue".

Comment: If you can't implement the second solution I mentioned, create a new post about it but show attempt you made to implement and I will take a look at it.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm going to open a new post about it

Comment: I've created this post with my implement but doesn't works. This is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50389586/show-images-downloaded-from-a-server-in-a-fast-way