# Show images downloaded from a server in a fast way

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a scene where I'd like to show multiple images downloaded from a server. I'm trying to download the textures and store them in a List. When the for loop finish running, I sort the List by name and then I instantiate the RawImage from the List, but doesn't works. What am I doing wrong?

```
public GameObject contentRef;
public RawImage imgPrefab;

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(DownloadtheFiles());
}

public IEnumerator DownloadtheFiles()
{
    yield return null;

    List<string> photolist = ES2.LoadList<string>("myPhotos.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < photolist.Count; i++)
    {
        //Don't capture i variable
        int index = i;

        bool reqDone = false;

        new GetUploadedRequest()

            .SetUploadId(photolist[index])
            .Send((response) =>
                {
                    StartCoroutine(DownloadImages(response.Url, index,
                        (status) => { reqDone = status; }));


                    //return null;
                });

        //Wait in the for loop until the current request is done
        while (!reqDone)
            yield return null;
    }
}

public IEnumerator DownloadImages(string downloadUrl, int index, Action<bool> done)
{
    var www = new WWW(downloadUrl);
    yield return www;

    //Get the downloaded image
    Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(4, 4);
    www.LoadImageIntoTexture(tex);

    List <Texture2D> texList = new List <Texture2D> ();

    for (int i = 0; i < tex.Count; i++)
    {
        texList.Add (tex);
    }

    texList = texList.OrderBy(mtex => mtex.name).ToList();

    for (int i = 0; i < tex.Count; i++)
    {
        RawImage newImg = Instantiate(imgPrefab, contentRef.transform);
        //Change the name
        newImg.name = "Image-" + index;
        //Apply the downloaded image
        newImg.texture = tex;
    }

    //Done
    if (done != null)
        done(true);
}
```

}

Comment: Could you give more detail than "but doesn't works"? Note that although you're calling `Instantiate` to create a `RawImage`, you're not doing anything with it afterwards other than settings fields. Does `Instantiate` do something with the `RawImage` it creates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `RawImage` code should be done outside the `DownloadImages` function because `DownloadImages` is called to download image from the url in the `for` loop. The `RawImage` instantiation should be done only after the `for` loop has completed.

Also, using `texList.OrderBy(mtex => mtex.name).ToList();` wouldn't work because your string contains both string and int and is in this format *"Image-" + 0;"*. You will need a custom function to do that by splitting the `string` and `int` then sorting with the `int`.

Finally, after the `for` loop has finished running, you need a way to determine that all images has finished downloading before instantiating the `RawImages`. You can do this by using array or List of `bool` with the size of the `List<string> photolist` that contains the link of images to download. Pass that array of bool to the `DownloadImages` and use the `index` argument to set it to `true` when each download is done.

```
public GameObject contentRef;
public RawImage imgPrefab;

List<Texture2D> downloadedTextures = new List<Texture2D>();

void Start()
{
    DownloadtheFiles();
}

public void DownloadtheFiles()
{

    List<string> photolist = ES2.LoadList<string>("myPhotos.txt");

    //Used to determine when were done downloading
    bool[] doneDownloading = new bool[photolist.Count];

    //Download images only.Don't instantiate anything
    for (int i = 0; i < photolist.Count; i++)
    {
        //Don't capture i variable
        int index = i;

        new GetUploadedRequest()

            .SetUploadId(photolist[index])
            .Send((response) =>
            {
                StartCoroutine(DownloadImages(response.Url, index, doneDownloading));
            });
    }

    //Instantiate the download images
    StartCoroutine(InstantiateImages(doneDownloading));
}

//Instantiates the downloaded images after they are done downloading
IEnumerator InstantiateImages(bool[] downloadStatus)
{
    //Wait until all images are done downloading
    for (int i = 0; i < downloadStatus.Length; i++)
    {
        while (!downloadStatus[i])
            yield return null;
    }

    //Sort the images by string
    sort(ref downloadedTextures);

    //Now, instantiate the images
    for (int i = 0; i < downloadedTextures.Count; i++)
    {
        //Instantiate the image prefab GameObject and make it a child of the contentRef
        RawImage newImg = Instantiate(imgPrefab, contentRef.transform);

        //Apply the downloaded image
        newImg.texture = downloadedTextures[i];

        //Update name so that we can see the names in the Hierarchy
        newImg.name = downloadedTextures[i].name;
    }

    //Clear List for next use
    downloadedTextures.Clear();
}

//Sort the downloaded Textures by name
void sort(ref List<Texture2D> targetList)
{
    var ordered = targetList.Select(s => new { s, Str = s.name, Split = s.name.Split('-') })
    .OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.Split[1]))
    .ThenBy(x => x.Split[0])
    .Select(x => x.s)
    .ToList();

    targetList = ordered;
}

public IEnumerator DownloadImages(string downloadUrl, int index, bool[] downloadStatus)
{
    //Download image
    var www = new WWW(downloadUrl);
    yield return www;

    //Get the downloaded image and add it to the List
    Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(4, 4);
    //Change the name
    tex.name = "Image-" + index;
    www.LoadImageIntoTexture(tex);
    downloadedTextures.Add(tex);

    downloadStatus[index] = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! I've tested it and this error appears in line 46 ("return null;") : "error CS8030: Anonymous function or lambda expression converted to a void returning delegate cannot return a value"

Comment: Not sure why it took you this long to respond. I removed `Action<bool>` from the code and it should just work if you copy the code from this answer and paste it. Now, if you still get an error, you have to post the code that's causing that error.

Comment: Sorry to answer so late but I have been traveling without the laptop. I've copied the code but this error appears: Assets/_TES/Scripts/ImageManager_DEF.cs(46,7): error CS8030: Anonymous function or lambda expression converted to a void returning delegate cannot return a value. Should I open a new post?

Comment: This doesn't require a new question since it's a problem with the code in the answer. Remove the `return null;` that is under           `StartCoroutine(DownloadImages(response.Url, index, doneDownloading));`  in the `DownloadtheFiles` function. I mistakenly included that during copy and paste.

Comment: Ok!! Now works fine and faster than the other solution. THANK YOU SO MUCH !!

Comment: Yup. That's because it starts all the coroutine at the-same time then waits for all of them to finish *instead starting one and waiting for that one to finish before starting the next one.* You are welcome!